# Window location reload true

Tags: javascript, html, safari, onclick, href

```
<a href="#sishane" onclick="window.location.reload( true );">- Şişhane</a>
```

This code does not work in Safari.

I need to reload links as I call them from within the line, but this code does not work in safari

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp). It says to use `true` when reloading a page from server and `false` if reloading from cache. Try using simply `window.location.reload()` or `window.location.reload(false)`.

Comment: The code you submitted **does** reload the page in Safari, I just tested it. I see you have a #hashtag in your href, what is your goal? Do you need to reload the page after the url hash has changed?

Comment: Reloading the page but the address I want is not going

Comment: I have used the code "window.location.reload ()" because the url looks like I'm calling it as a line,

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "url looks like I'm calling it as a line". For this particular example, as I understand, first you want the url to change to {{....#sichane}} and then you want to reload the page? Is that your goal?

Comment: That's what I want;

I want to go to the page after you have renovated.
Because when I can not renew, the url becomes #sishane but it does not go to the page I want.
Safari does not work, page refreshes, but does not go to the page I want.